# Display images after augmentation in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

How can I display all images after augmentation?

How can I get the number of the trained data after augmentation?

Thank you

Comment: Are you following any book or resource?

Comment: No, but I have applied data augmentation and I would like to display it.

Comment: No, but I have applied data augmentation and I would like to display it.

Comment: Try to follow a book/resource on deep learning. You will find these kind of tasks there along with the code. One in particular - http://www.deeplearningitalia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Dropbox_Chollet.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the kind of data set you are using you can use `.flow` (if you have data as numpy arrays) or `.flow_from_directory` (if you have images in file system) to run through the [data generator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) and save the output using `save_to_dir` argument.

Comment: save_to_dir  saves the images. Thank you for the solution.